# MYSQL update statement doesn't work on Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query which works fine in MySQL,

```
update rpt_dev a inner join rpt_dev_temp b
on a.Interaction_UDL = b.Interaction_UDL
set a.Till_Next = datediff(b.Int_start,a.Int_start)
where a.Till_Next <= 0 and 
a.Int_start not in (select max(a.Int_start) from rpt_dev_temp a);
```

When I run it on Oracle I get the below errors:

> 1) SQL command not properly ended.
>
> 2) Missing set keyword

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: 1) SQL command not properly ended.
2) Missing set keyword

Comment: DATEDIFF is not an Oracle function.

Comment: yeah i have removed datediff and used (b.Int_start-a.Int_start)

Comment: Update statements work bit differently in Oracle. If you can give sample data for both tables and the expected output, maybe someone can come up with a query

Comment: Where in the Oracle manual did you find that syntax?

Answer (score 1):

Update statements with join are bit tricky to implement in Oracle. Use `MERGE` instead

Also as mentioned in comments, `datediff` is not valid in Oracle. So subtracts dates directly. But `b.Int_start - a.Int_start` will give you difference in `days`. Multiply it by `24` or `24*60` or `24*60*60` to get difference in `hours` , `minutes` and `seconds` respectively.

```
merge into rpt_dev a
using rpt_dev_temp b
on (a.Interaction_UDL = b.Interaction_UDL)
when matched then update 
set a.Till_Next = (b.Int_start - a.Int_start)
where a.Till_Next <= 0 and 
a.Int_start not in (select max(Int_start) from rpt_dev_temp);
```

Note: Take backup of your original data before running. Test it on your test data and do no commit until you are sure you are updating correct rows.

In short, run update/delete statements with extra caution.

Comment: Thank you let me check with the sample data.

Comment: As I said update is tricky to implement, hence use `merge` instead. In `merge` when you specify `when matched then update` , then it will on `update` on matching rows.